# Sort session PHP and MSSQL

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, database

I'm new using MSSQL and PHP, and I want to sort results from a session, not from a link like sort.php?id.. Anyone can help me doing that?

Here is my code:

```
    <body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <h1 align="center" >Tickets - Informática</h1>
     <table class="tablesorter" id="keywords" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="lalign">#</th>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Idade</th>
      <th>Peso</th>
        </tr>
  </thead>

<tbody>
<?php
        $serverName = "asfdasasx-fsadasd"; 
        $options = array(  "UID" => "safs",  "PWD" => "fsadas",  "Database" => "demo");
        $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $options);
            if( $conn ) {
            $sql="SELECT * FROM cliente";
            $aResult=sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
            while($rows = sqlsrv_fetch_array($aResult))
            { 
            $id = $rows['id'];
            $nome = $rows['nome'];
            $idade = $rows['idade'];
            $peso = $rows['peso'];
?>
<p>
    <td align="center"><b><?php echo $id;?></b></td>
    <td align="center"><b><?php echo $nome;?></b></td>
    <td align="center"><b><?php echo $idade;?></b></td>
    <td align="center"><b><?php echo $peso;?></b></td>
</p>
</tbody>
```

Comment: What about sorting using sql queries?

Comment: I already see that and I didnt put it working, so I ask some help

Comment: Can you elaborate `sort results from a session`? I can't see `session` being used in your codes

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really hard to understand. I'm guessing you want the results of the query to be sorted; if so, just add

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM cliente ORDER BY 'nome' ASC";
```

instead of just:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM cliente";
```

You change the name of the field, to order the table by it, changing ***"nome"*** to the name of any other row's name.

Comment: It's like that, but I want use it for all, for 'id', for 'nome', for 'peso', for 'idade'

Comment: Just add a coma to separate each field you want.
For example: "SELECT * FROM cliente ORDER BY 'id' ASC, 'nome' ASC, 'peso' DESC, 'idade' DESC"